# Time difference between two times in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

(Please note that I have seen a similar question on StackOverflow recently, however I can not find it anywhere - if anyone can find it please post the link)

I have a table that has a datetime field in it. For example:

**Table data**

```
DateTime date;
int number;
```

I need to find the difference between date in a row and date in the next row. I have tried with a query:

```
select date as current_date, date - (select top 1 date where date > current_date from data) as time_difference from date
```

however this won't work, because of "current_date". Is there a way I can do this with one query?

Comment: How do you define the next row?

Comment: Next row is the one with closest larger date in the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  date AS current_date, next_date - date AS difference
FROM    mytable mo
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 date AS next_date
        FROM    mytable mi
        WHERE   mi.date > mo.date
        ORDER BY
                date
        ) q
```